# Exporting all clients does not work, the file is saved with no name and no extension

Tags: laravel, export, export-to-csv, laravel-9

I am trying to export the data in my database; in particular all the customers present but also a single chosen customer.

I tried to set the code only that when I click the button to export all clients a file with no name and no extension is saved.

**ClientsExport Class**

```
class ClientsExport implements FromCollection
{
    private $client = null;

    public function __construct($client = null)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function collection(Client $client=NULL)
    {
        if ($this->client) {
            return collect([$this->client]);
        }

        return Client::all();
    }

}
```

Taking a few tries I found that if I remove the if in the code below, then leaving it alone

> return Excel::download(new ClientsExport, 'clients.xlsx');

it works properly, So it seems that the problem is giving it the if

**ClientController**

```
public function export(Client $client) 
    {
        if($client){
            return Excel::download(new ClientsExport($client), $client->surname . ' ' .  $client->name . '.xlsx');
        } else {
            return Excel::download(new ClientsExport, 'clients.xlsx');   
        } 
    }
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('client-export/{client?}', [ClientController::class,'export'])->name('client.export');
```

**View Blade**

> *Button where I want to export all clients*

```
<a class="btn btn-warning mb-5 py-3 px-4 mt-3 me-3 fs-5" href="{{ route('client.export') }}">Export all clients</a>
```

> *Button where I want to export the individual client*

```
<a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{ route('client.export' , compact('client')) }}">Export</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when using [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding), defining your controller method as: `public function export(Client $client)` will supply you with a new *"empty"* instance of `\App\Models\Client` when the *client id* in your route definition is *"empty"*. Hence, the check below in your controller method will **always** be truthy.

**ClientController::export(\App\Models\Client $client)**

```php
       if($client){
            // ...
        } else {
            // ...  
        }
```

To fix that, you will have to **explicitly** set the Controller method's parameter to `NULL`. This will instruct Laravel's route model binding system to supply you with a `NULL` `$client` variable instead of an "empty" instance of the `Client` model (`new \App\Models\Client`) when the *client id* in your route definition is *"empty"*. ie:

**ClientController** class

```php
// ...
    public function export(\App\Models\Client $client = null)
    {

    }
// ...
```

##### FULL SOLUTION

**ClientsExport** Class

```php
class ClientsExport implements FromCollection
{
    public function __construct(private ?\App\Models\Client $client = null)
    {
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return is_null($this->client)
            ? Client::all()
            : collect([
                $this->client
            ]);
    }

}
```

**ClientController** class

```php
// ...
    public function export(\App\Models\Client $client = null)
    {
        return Excel::download(new ClientsExport($client),
            is_null($client)
                ? 'clients.xlsx'
                : $client->surname . ' ' . $client->name . '.xlsx'
        );
    }
// ...
```

Comment: Perfect, it works correctly. I thank you infinitely. One question. What does that mean ? in this line `public function __construct(private ?\App\Models\Client $client = null)` ?

Comment: @Sarah [PHP 8: Constructor property promotion](https://stitcher.io/blog/constructor-promotion-in-php-8)

Comment: @Sarah [Constructor Promotion](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.constructor.promotion)

Comment: @Sarah https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#constructor-property-promotion

Comment: I know this, I mean the ? before \App\Models\Client $client = null in construct function

Comment: @Sarah [Nullable type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php#language.types.declarations.nullable)

Comment: Perfect, I thank you infinitely